# Displaying a Javascript array in HTML with spaces

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I have an array in a Javascript file that I want to display on my web page.

However, when I do it using

```
document.getElementById("fullVerb").innerHTML = thisVerb;
```

it is displayed without spaces. 
Like: first,second,third

How do I make it normally spaced (i.e. first, second, third)?

I can't just write the array in the HTML because it changes.

Comment: Use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join): `thisVerb.join(', ');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for that purpose:

```
thisVerb = ['first', 'second', 'last'];
document.getElementById("fullVerb").innerHTML = thisVerb.join(', ');
// gets you: "first, second, last"
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/hjLrhbsv/)